# How to get certbot docker to generate pems?

Tags: docker, nginx, ssh, docker-compose, certbot

So I'm following this tutorial [how to secure a containerized nod js app](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-secure-a-containerized-node-js-application-with-nginx-let-s-encrypt-and-docker-compose). I was able to get to the point where they generate the certs. When I run the following command `docker-compose up --force-recreate --no-deps certbot` I'm faced with

> Attaching to certbot certbot      | There seem to be problems with
> that address. Enter email address (used for certbot      | urgent
> renewal and security notices) certbot      | certbot      | certbot
> | If you really want to skip this, you can run the client with certbot
> | **--register-unsafely-without-email** but you will then be unable to
> receive notice certbot      | about impending expiration or revocation
> of your certificates or problems with certbot      | your Certbot
> installation that will lead to failure to renew. certbot      |
> certbot      |  (Enter 'c' to cancel): Saving debug log to
> /var/log/letsencrypt/letsencrypt.log certbot      | An unexpected
> error occurred: certbot      | EOFError certbot      | Ask for help or
> search for solutions at https://community.letsencrypt.org. See the
> logfile /var/log/letsencrypt/letsencrypt.log or re-run Certbot with -v
> for more details. certbot exited with code 1

The command in the docker-compose.yml is as followed.
`command: certonly --webroot --webroot-path=/var/www/html --email sammy@example.local --agree-tos --no-eff-email --register-unsafely-without-email --force-renewal -d example.local -d www.example.local`
Which you can see has **--register-unsafely-without-email**.

After making the nessasary adjustments to the nginx.conf, the webserver has an error

> nginx: [emerg] cannot load certificate "/etc/letsencrypt/live/example.local/fullchain.pem"

I then commented out the newly added nginx.conf context. Then I went into the webserver container to check if the live folder exists. No supprize, there is no folder live within /etc/letsencrypt.

What is the solution to get this command to work?

- I only need this for local development, so keeping it simple is ideal.
- I do need to have SSH.

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue.

> certbot      | The server will not issue certificates for the
> identifier :: Error creating new order :: Cannot issue for
> "example.local": Domain name does not end with a valid public suffix
> (TLD) (and 1 more problems. Refer to sub-problems for more
> information.)

[Certbot must have public domain](https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/name-does-not-end-in-a-public-suffix/77293/2)